# App crashing after clicking on button styled with pixate

Tags: android, css, button, click, pixate

My app was working fine but after adding the button in default.css I get the following error on clicking the button

```
 02-27 07:42:33.003: E/AndroidRuntime(1944): java.lang.StackOverflowError
 02-27 07:42:33.003: E/AndroidRuntime(1944):    at java.util.WeakHashMap.poll(WeakHashMap.java:569)
 02-27 07:42:33.003: E/AndroidRuntime(1944):    at java.util.WeakHashMap.getEntry(WeakHashMap.java:496)
 02-27 07:42:33.003: E/AndroidRuntime(1944):    at java.util.WeakHashMap.containsKey(WeakHashMap.java:280)
 02-27 07:42:33.003: E/AndroidRuntime(1944):    at com.pixate.freestyle.PXHierarchyListener.addGlobalLayoutListener(PXHierarchyListener.java:184)
 02-27 07:42:33.003: E/AndroidRuntime(1944):    at com.pixate.freestyle.PXHierarchyListener.setFor(PXHierarchyListener.java:114)
 02-27 07:42:33.003: E/AndroidRuntime(1944):    at com.pixate.freestyle.util.ViewUtil.prepareViewGroupListeners(ViewUtil.java:113)
 02-27 07:42:33.003: E/AndroidRuntime(1944):    at com.pixate.freestyle.PXHierarchyListener.onChildViewAdded(PXHierarchyListener.java:66)
 02-27 07:42:33.003: E/AndroidRuntime(1944):    at android.widget.TableLayout$PassThroughHierarchyChangeListener.onChildViewAdded(TableLayout.java:771)
 02-27 07:42:33.003: E/AndroidRuntime(1944):    at com.pixate.freestyle.PXHierarchyListener.onChildViewAdded(PXHierarchyListener.java:85)
```

default.css

```
#views1{
background-color:#FFFFFF;
height: 35px;
border-radius  : 5px;
border-width   : 3px;
border-color   :  #3369e8 ;
color :   #3369e8 ;
}

#views1:pressed{
background-color:#3369e8;
height: 35px;
border-radius  : 5px;
border-width   : 3px;
border-color   :  #3369e8;
color :   #FFFFFF;
}
```

here views1 is the name of the button

Note: button is styled properly by pixate but app crashes on clicking it

On clickListener for views1

```
   views1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {    
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Bundle bu = new Bundle();
            bu.putInt("num", 1);
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivityParser.this,ViewSample.class);
         i.putExtras(bu);
           startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

Comment: post the code where you call `OnClickListener`

Comment: I have added the on clicklistener for views1. ViewSample is an activity which displays the content of a file

Comment: I think I got what the problem may be. view1 is in a grid view and I think that is what causing the problem because when i used pixate to style a button outside gridview it worked perfectly.Is there some way to do the same to the buttons which are inside the gridview?

Comment: Could you attach the code on how view1 is instantiated? I tried with an adapter to create the list of buttons in GridView, and it worked fine.

Comment: Also what version of Android SDK the app is running on?